# Cannot convert List to IEnumerable in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

I want to store some collection properties in `string` column in database.
Some of them are `IEnumerable<>` and some are `List<>`

Using `Ef core` I've created such a extension method:

```
public static void StringWithStyleConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> builder)
    where T : IEnumerable<StringWithStyle>
{
    builder.HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
        ,
        new ValueComparer<T>(
            (arr1, arr2) => arr1.Count() == arr2.Count() && !arr1.Except(arr2).Any(),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => new List<StringWithStyle>(c))
        );
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<TypiconOnline.Domain.ItemTypes.StringWithStyle>' to 'T'
```

on a line:

```
c => new List<StringWithStyle>(c))
```

Could you please help me, how can it be solved?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I've already found an answer

```
c => (T) Convert.ChangeType(new List<StringWithStyle>(c)), typeof (T))
```

**UPDATE**

It doesn't work. Because `List<StringWithStyle>` doesn't implement `IConvertible`

Comment: Can you also try `.AsEnumerable()`?

`c => new List<StringWithStyle>(c).AsEnumerable())`

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti with `.AsEnumerable()` as well the cast `(T)` is needed. its a puzzle. The puzzle is why covariance wont work here?

Comment: @GertArnold: `(T)` cast is still required.